# get list of unique months from pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following pandas `date_range`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('9/1/2017', '12/31/2017')
```

I want to get a list of the unique months. This is what I've come up with so far but there has to be a better way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng})
months = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')).agg('sum').index.tolist()
formatted_m = [i.strftime('%m/%Y') for i in months]
# ['09/2017', '10/2017', '11/2017', '12/2017']
```

Note the dates will be stored in a DataFrame column or index.

Comment: May I ask which solution you were asking for?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) because [`DatetmeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetmeIndex.strftime.html) return `numpy array`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('9/1/2017', '12/31/2017')
print (np.unique(rng.strftime('%m/%Y')).tolist())
['09/2017', '10/2017', '11/2017', '12/2017']
```

If input is column of `DataFrame` use [Anton vBR's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47759061/2901002):

```
print(df['date'].dt.strftime("%m/%y").unique().tolist())
```

Or [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print(df['date'].dt.strftime("%m/%y").drop_duplicates().tolist())
```

**Timings**:

All solution have same performance  - unique vs drop_duplicates:

```
rng = pd.date_range('9/1/1900', '12/31/2017')

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng})

In [54]: %timeit (df['date'].dt.strftime("%m/%y").unique().tolist())
1 loop, best of 3: 469 ms per loop

In [56]: %timeit (df['date'].dt.strftime("%m/%y").drop_duplicates().tolist())
1 loop, best of 3: 466 ms per loop
```

Comment: Damn it.. I think this must be quicker again! .. But wait.. you are calling the range and not the dataframe column. The range is just to create the data sample I think.

Comment: Ok now you added my solution +1 :)

Comment: Or better remove code, only link to you? What is better?

Comment: I don't mind. I think OP is asking for my solution though. Let's see.

Comment: @AntonvBR you're correct. The range was simply for building the DataFrame. This answer covers it all though thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyMetz We're just glad we could help. I won this one though :p. I think drop_duplicates isn't really needed here as it really doesn't add any extra value in this case (less readable).

Answer (score 5):

Yes or this:

```
df['date'].dt.strftime("%m/%y").unique().tolist()
#['09/17', '10/17', '11/17', '12/17']
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not need to build the df

```
(rng.year*100+rng.month).value_counts().index.tolist()
Out[861]: [201712, 201710, 201711, 201709]
```

Updated :

```
set((rng.year*100+rng.month).tolist())
Out[865]: {201709, 201710, 201711, 201712}
```

Comment: A bit different, but plus1 :)

Comment: @jezrael yeah , little different for the `value_counts`:-)

Comment: It's smart but unnecessary I think as unique() probably is faster. This is great if you need the amounts though.

Comment: I like the set solution. However I still think this is wrong as OP is asking for a column operation and not range. What I guess.

Comment: @Wen - there is problem with `set` you need sort, check it with more data.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this one and I think it's quite straightforward:

```
rng.month.unique()
```

Edit: Probably not relevant any longer, but just for the sake of completeness:

```
set([str(year)+str(month) for year , month in zip(rng.year,rng.month)])
```

Comment: This is wrong as it only takes the month in consideration. We need month and year.

Comment: I just read he/she wanted a list of unique months :(  gotta be more careful reading the posts!